# background color changes of customtkinter button when it get pressed and also text color changes

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter, ttkbootstrap

In my ctk (customtkinter) project, color of button changes when it gets pressed also text's color changes from white to black. When the button is pressed it calls gen_table which creates a ttkbootstrap table on ttkbootstrap window. Below are two images of button before and after it is pressed.

[image: Before]

[image: after]

Here is the sample code

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import ttkbootstrap
from ttkbootstrap.tableview import Tableview
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

def gen_table():
    app = ttkbootstrap.Window()

    coldata = ["LicenseNumber", "company name", "text"]

    rowdata = [
        ("A123", "IzzyCo", 12),
    ]
    dt = Tableview(
        master=app,
        coldata=coldata,
        rowdata=rowdata,
        searchable=True,
        bootstyle=PRIMARY,
        stripecolor=("lightgreen", None),
    )
    dt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, padx=10, pady=10)

    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainWindow = ctk.CTk()
    btn = ctk.CTkButton(
        master=mainWindow,
        text="something",
        bg_color="transparent",
        hover_color="red",
        command=lambda: gen_table(),
    ).grid()
    mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to call `app.mainloop()` inside `gen_table()`.

Answer (score 0):

In tkinter, bg is the property for the background, while fg is for the font color. However, in customtkinter, fg_color is the background color, not the text color (there is a separate parameter for text_color). In the documentation, there is no bg_color, likely because customtkinter is using it to change color based on the theme.

To override the color, just use fg_color.

However, for your code, it seems you can just omit this parameter altogether since transparent shouldn't change the look at all.